# PayPal IPN Integration (Express Checkout - Razor/C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am currently trying to integrate PayPal with my site, and everything's gone well - up to the point where we do our IPN checking thing.

It gets right down to the if/elseif/else block and that's where it ends. It outputs a message, that reads:

"Invalid status. form_charset=UTF8"

Here is the code that I have.

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@using System.Text
@using System.Web
@using System.Web.UI
@using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using System.ComponentModel

@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Checkout | SSSSS";

    string postUrl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(param);
    string ipnPost = strRequest;
    strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //for proxy
    //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
    //req.Proxy = proxy;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), 
                             System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);

    streamOut.Close();

    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();

    /*/ logging ipn messages... be sure that you give write
    // permission to process executing this code
    string logPathDir = ResolveUrl("Messages");
    string logPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}.txt", 
                     Server.MapPath(logPathDir), DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    File.WriteAllText(logPath, ipnPost);
    /*/

}
@if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
{
    /*---------------- WILL DO OTHER CHECKS LATER    ------------------*/
    //check the payment_status is Completed
    <p>status is verified</p>
    //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    //process payment
}
else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
{
    //log for manual investigation
    <p>status is invalid.</p>

<p>@ipnPost</p>
}
else
{
    //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
    <p>status is invalid.</p>
<p>@ipnPost</p>
}
```

I'm at a complete loss as to why this isn't working as expected; I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Thanks @jason, using the above example (I had found almost identical code elsewhere but wasn't able to get it too work but have just come across this and now am successfully receiving IPN notification so just thought I'd share my thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not fluent in Razor, but here is how I do my asp.net webforms one. I believe this was from another website(or most of it anyway), and I sadly don't remember where. So credit is not mine for the basics of this code.

```
string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strLive); 
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
streamOut.Write(strRequest);
streamOut.Close();
StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
streamIn.Close();

NameValueCollection ppDetails = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strRequest);
if (strResponse == "VERIFIED"){
if (ppDetails["payment_status"] == "Completed"){
//yay, give them goodies
} else if (strResponse == "INVALID"){
//log IP and possibly block them from your web services if malicious
} else {
//log response/ipn data for manual investigation
}
}
```

The main difference seems to be that you use UTF8, and the code I have that works uses ASCII.  I also added the 'ppDetails' part to give you an idea of how to handle the variables.

Hope it helps. Took me forever to figure out Paypal IPN, and once I did, I felt so silly.

Comment: we're both using the same code lol. Mine was also originally ASCII - But was told to change it to UTF8 because the ASCII part was generating errors "form_charset=UTF8" (thats with the ascii stuff) - but still, after changing to UTF8 - It still isn't working

Comment: thanks for adding that extra part for handling the variables - much appreciated

Comment: @jason Have you tried printing out strResponse? Instead of just checking if it is a specific set of words

Comment: Thanks, @JClaspill - Just tried that, with "@strResponse" and it outputs "INVALID"

Comment: @jason Be sure you use the paypal developer sandbox site for testing this. I assume you are, but if not check here: https://developer.paypal.com/   and change your strLive url to "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?"

Comment: Other than that, I'm not sure what causes an INVALID response. Beyond the system not thinking you are checking on a valid transaction

Comment: Well I ended up printing out onto the page the full query string received by PayPal and the params say st=Complete.      And the transaction I'd (tx=blahblahblah) shows up as well and when I do: if(Request["st"]=="Complete") it recognizes it, but if(VERIFIED) is still always invalid